# How to resolve LDAP: error code 19 - pwdFailureTime: no user modification allowed for OPEN LDAP

Tags: directory, ldap, openldap, ldap-query

While unlocking an account I am getting error message as :
LDAP: error code 19 - pwdFailureTime: no user modification allowed

Tried giving different values for the attribute 'pwdAccountlockedtime' on LDAP managed system from apache Directory Studio, but getting same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Error Code 19 : constraintViolation

"Indicates that the client supplied an attribute value that does not conform to the constraints placed upon it by the data model." See [OpenLdap Doc](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/appendix-ldap-result-codes.html)

You are not allowed to change pwdFailureTime. It is defined in the passwordpolicy.

**Unlock User:**

Modify userPassword with admin Privileges. Depending on your policy settings (passwordMustChange, etc.)  user should change his initial password to a final (not initial Password). Then will be nsAccountLock "automatically" cleared.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, will try the operation after changing the policy and check.